# Compiling java class with a non-default package name

Tags: java

How to compile a java class (let's say SomeClass.java) which belongs to a package (let's say com.hello) via the command-line. Simply saying javac SomeClass.java does not work. I have read that I must use the -cp flag, but the question is how and why?

Answer (score 0):

Your source file should be in a folder called `hello`, inside a folder called `com`.

Go to the directory that contains `com` and run:

```
javac com/hello/SomeClass.java
```